# Instantiating SQLAlchemy engine from DBAPI connection object

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy, python-db-api

I'm using SQLAlchemy from within Django, and I can access the thread-local [database connection object in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/#connections-and-cursors):

`from django.db import connection`

Given that `connection` object, can I use it to instantiate a SQLAlchemy engine?

All of the documentation I've read about creating a SQLAlchemy engine requires providing a database URL string.

Is there a way I can create an SA engine by providing an existing connection?

My goal here is to avoid opening 2 database connections where I do not have to.

Comment: Yes it can be done -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743336/in-sqlalchemy-can-i-create-an-engine-from-an-existing-odbc-connection#answer-23744051

Comment: Oh! Thank you Chelsea

Comment: The problem with the referenced answer it that it doesn't continue the transaction on that connection. (at least for psycopg2 -- sadface)